# Compactifications of group varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $V$ be a nonempty, irreducible, smooth projective variety over $\mathbf{C}$.

> Is there a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbf{C}$, a surjective map $X\to V$ of varieties over $\mathbf{C}$, such that $X$ contains as a dense open $\mathbf{C}$-subscheme some $\mathbf{C}$-group scheme $G$ of finite type?

Abelian varieties and toric varieties are of course examples with $X=V$.

Comment: When you say "contains as dense open subscheme some group scheme", do you mean, "contains a dense open subscheme that admits a structure of group scheme"?

Comment: (Certainly $X$ should be assumed irreducible, otherwise we obtain an uninteresting trivial yes as soon as $V$ is nonempty. Also $V$ should in any case be assumed to be nonempty.)

Comment: No. Any smooth projective curve of genus $> 1$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: @naf Could you clarify what you have in mind? You must be implying that this statement implies that $C$ itself must be a group scheme, in which case I agree $C$ can only be of genus $0$ or $1$, but I don't see this implication.

Comment: @JohnPilud Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $>1$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $C$ has a dense open $U$ which can be endowed with the structure of a group scheme. A connected finite type group scheme  over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m$, $\mathbb{G}_a$ or an elliptic curve. So $U$ is isomorphic to a dense open of a curve of genus $<2$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I know this. The question asks for something else. Take $V = C$ in the question, for $C$ a curve of genus $>1$. Are you saying that there can be no surjection $X\to C$ with $X$ smooth projective, such that $X$ contains an open dense sub-scheme of finite type with a group scheme structure? I do agree that $X = C$ doesn't work unless $C$ has genus $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @JohnPilud Let $G$ be a connected finite type group scheme. Then, every morphism $G\to C$ is constant. To prove this, first assume $G$ is linear. Then $G$ is covered by copies of $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{0\}$. But every $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{0\}$ maps trivially to $C$. Thus, if $G$ is arbitrary, the linear part of $G$ (provided by Chevalley's structure theorem) is contracted to a point. So we can deal with $G$ modulo its linear part. This is an abelian variety. But a higher genus curve is not dominated by any abelian variety. You can prove this in several ways...continued below.

Comment: One way: Let $A\to C$ be a dominant morphism with $A$ an abelian variety. Then, this gives you a non-constant holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}\to C^{an}$ (use that $A$ is uniformised by affine space). But there are no such holomorphc maps to a hyperbolic curve (such as $C$), because such a map would lift to the universal cover, and the universal cover is isomorphic to a bounded domain and every bounded holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ is constant.

Comment: Second way: the Kodaira dimension of $A$ is zero and the Kodaira dimension of $C$ is one. Thus, there can be no dominant morphism from $A\to C$. (Pull-back differentials....)

Comment: All in all, as naf said, every smooth projective curve of genus $>1$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: Reference for the above argument: Lemma 2.5 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03665

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thank you so much! Now all is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smooth projective curves of genus $>1$ are counterexamples. To see this, you can use the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a  proper integral variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Then the following are equivalent.

1. For every abelian variety $A$, every morphism $A\to X$ is constant.
2. For every finite type connected group scheme $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$, every morphism $G\to X$ is constant.

A proof of this lemma is given in Lemma 2.5 of arxiv.org/abs/1807.03665

To show that smooth projective curves of genus $g>1$ give counterexamples, we can argue as follows:

> > Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g>1$. Then, every morphism from an abelian variety $A$ to $X$ is constant. This can be seen by using the uniformisation of $A$ by affine $\dim(A)$-space or by pulling-back differentials. Now, by the above Lemma, every morphism $G\to X$ is constant, where $G$ is any finite type connected group scheme over $\mathbb{C}$. But this implies that every morphism $Y\to X$ is constant, where $Y$ is a variety containing a dense open isomorphic to the variety underlying a finite type connected group scheme.

Note: Any hyperbolic variety gives a counterexample. For example, the moduli space of genus $q$ ($q>1$) smooth proper curves with level $N$ ($N>3$) structure.